# How host Test Link on static IP for second time

Tags: mysql, apache, testlink

I have hosted the Testlink on my machine(static IP was - 10.0.4.6) and now my new static IP is 192.168.4.6 
  problem is I can access the Testlink with my static IP but my teammates can't ( can't access Testlink from other machines)

Comment: are your teammates in the same network or is your network open for access from other networks? if not...that's the reason

Comment: my teammates are on the same network.

Comment: ok. so, can your teammates access other services on your machine? can they access, e.g., a shared folder, or simply see your machine listed in the network? remote diagnostics are pretty hard in such cases ;) but another reason could be that your computer blocks the range of 192.168.4.*
try changing it to 192.168.1.* since this just is more common for local networks and less blocked by default